# Android emulator failed

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Ubuntu 15 IntelliJ IDEA

emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
ERROR: Could not create SDL2 window: Failed loading libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I also tried following commands

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev

cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/
sudo ln -s libGL.so.1.2 libGL.so 
sudo ln -s libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/libGL.so
ln -s libGL.so.1.2 ~/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGL.so

ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 ~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib/libGL.so
```

Comment: Why do you shout in your questions title?

Comment: @arkascha perhaps he has a bad sector somewhere ? ;-)

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri` and 
`$ sudo ln -sv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`

Comment: root@user-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~# sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
root@user-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~# sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

Comment: libegl1-mesa : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (= 11.0.2-1ubuntu4) but 11.2~git1602150730.5d87a7~gd~w is to be installed
 libgbm1 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (= 11.0.2-1ubuntu4) but 11.2~git1602150730.5d87a7~gd~w is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-nouveau2 (>= 2.4.66+git1602130630.9b7744~gd~w) but 2.4.64-1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libllvm3.8 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@user-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~# sudo ln -sv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so’: File exists

Answer (score 0):

Use Genymotion, it is free and one of the bests.
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/